# hide and show click items on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to hide and show elements in the time-line based on year.

suppose use clicks on year `2015` then it should hide all it child element and show it if user clicks  the same year again `2015`.

I have modified following HTML and CSS as per my design,  original script can be found here `http://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-timeline/`

I have setup fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6nvumkxc/2/

when i click on the year it only hides the first element not all the `cd-timeline-block` in that particular year block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have used `.next()` with current context. it will only target next first sibling and not all of them. you need to modify click handler to:

```
$('.cd-year').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.cd-timeline-block').slideToggle();
});
```

or

```
$('.cd-year').click(function(){
   $(this).nextAll().slideToggle();
});
```

or

```
$('.cd-year').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().slideToggle();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pe2r0jgf/)**

**Update:**  For keeping only first year options open:

```
$('.cd-year').click(function(){
   $(this).nextAll().slideToggle();
}).not(':first').click();
```

**[Demo with first option open](http://jsfiddle.net/7nse5rLk/)**

Comment: How can i keep all minimized by default or keep first year option open only. I will also try in meantime

Comment: `$('.cd-year').click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll().slideToggle();
}).not(':first').click();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use like this

```
$('.cd-year').click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll(".cd-timeline-block").slideToggle();
});
```

next() will get the next element only. You should use `.nextAll()` inorder to get all the elements.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6nvumkxc/3/)